# Выгрузка данных из таблицы MySQL на страницу

Tags: php, mysql

Делаю сайт через index.php. Есть страница `site.ru/page.php`, которая физически находится в `dir1/dir2/page.php`. Если я правильно понял, то путь до этого файла нужно брать из таблицы с данными для этого файла. А, если у нас есть страница по адресу `site.ru/another-page.php`, находящаяся в `dir3/dir4/another-page.php` и в другой таблице, то как я могу узнать из какой таблицы выгружать данные? Через `GET` я получаю только имя страницы (из URL).

Подскажите как быть. Возможно я неправильно или не до конца понял механизм получения страниц через единую точку входа.

Comment: Видимо в пятницу я сильно туплю или реально слишком непонятный вопрос? :-)

Comment: @Nilsan, как я вижу механизм образования страницы:

Comment: Не успел отредактировать.
@Nilsan, как я вижу механизм образования страницы:
Через GET получаю имя страницы page.php и кладу в переменную $alias. Дальше я смотрю в таблицу БД. Ищу соответствия по имени страницы.
$query = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE page_alias = '$alias'";
Получаю все необходимые данные, в том числе физическое расположение страницы. И подключаю ее
include 'dir1/dir2/page.php';
Вот и вопрос: как заранее узнать из какой таблицы выгружать данные.
Еще раз повторюсь, я возможно чего-то не понимаю, и делается это все по-другому.